# How to pull the last jsonPath value in Java?

Tags: java, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

Hello I wanted to ask how to retrieve the last value in a jsonPath

```
{
    "testing": [
        {
            "transactionId": "5a99dcf84b7f633a5489805d",
            "trackingId": "555112",
            "tn": "6095555112",
            "customerName": "John",
            "customerLastName": "Chan"
        },
        {
            "transactionId": "5a99dd3f4b7f633a54898068",
            "tn": "6095555112",
            "trackingId": "555112",
            "customerName": "Amanda",
            "customerLastName": "Brown"

        }
    ]
}
```

**My Java code Sample line**

```
System.out.println("response.prettyPrint() = " + response.jsonPath().getString("testing.transactionId"));
```

**Output**

```
response.prettyPrint() = 5a99dcf84b7f633a5489805d,5a99dcf84b7f633a5489805d
```

Right now it is printing all transactionIds. It should be only pulling the latest one meaning the bottom one where transactionId = "5a99dd3f4b7f633a54898068"

If a new value come in (through back end logic, will add another set of values into this). How can I write a line that will pull the latest values set?

**Example**

```
{
    "testing": [
        {
            "transactionId": "5a99dcf84b7f633a5489805d",
            "trackingId": "555112",
            "tn": "6095555112",
            "customerName": "John",
            "customerLastName": "Chan"
        },
        {
            "transactionId": "5a99dd3f4b7f633a54898068",
            "tn": "6095555112",
            "trackingId": "555112",
            "customerName": "Amanda",
            "customerLastName": "Brown"

        },
        {
            "transactionId": "newID",
            "tn": "6095555112",
            "trackingId": "555112",
            "customerName": "Amanda",
            "customerLastName": "Brown"

        },
    ]
}
```

Now that a new dataset has been stored, How will I write a java code that would pull the transactionId "NewID"?

I don't want to hardcode and write something like ".transactionId[0]" [1] or [2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well instead of using `getString` you can use `getList`
For e.g

```
List<String> strList = response.jsonPath().getList("testing.transactionId");

System.out.println("last value is " + strList.get(strList.size()-1))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much Arsal.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. I don't know the exact code but I know in an array you can get the last item like...

```
 ARRAY.get(ARRAY.size()-1)
```

I am not sure how to properly implement that in your JSON array but I hope this sends you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

With the Rest assured if you want to get the last item from array, you can use:

```
.extract()
.path("items[-1].value");
```